# Unresolved External Symbol LNK 2001

Tags: c++, unresolved-external

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;`

class divSales{
public:
    int sales[4];    

    void quarterSales(int q1, int q2, int q3, int q4){        
        sales[1] = q1;
        sales[2] = q2;
        sales[3] = q3;
        sales[4] = q4;    
    }

    void setTotalSales(int sales[]){
        totalSales = sales[1]+sales[2]+sales[3]+sales[4];
    }

    int getTotalSales(){
        return totalSales;
    }

private:    
    static int totalSales;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    divSales div;    
    int q1=0, q2=0, q3=0, q4=0;
    cin >> q1 >> q2 >> q3 >> q4;    
    div.quarterSales(q1,q2,q3,q4);    
    div.setTotalSales(div.sales);
    cout << div.getTotalSales();   
}
```

I apologize if I did not put my code on the website correctly, I am kind of new to this, but I have received an error in my code called

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int divSales::totalSales" (?totalSales@divSales@@0HA)
```

and I am clueless about what it is or how to fix it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must define `static int totalSales` member. For example, you can add this line after class declaration: `int divSales::totalSales = 0;`